# Using '/profiles' in a URL alias

Tags: 7

The path '/profiles' exists as a physical folder in the root of a Drupal install, which means adding a URL alias for a piece of content to '/profiles' will not work - a 403 error is the result.

Lucky 'ol me, for a particular project I have an SEO partner telling me that using that particular path is an absolute, categorical must; not having this would be proof that the Myan's doomsday prediction is in fact accurate, we'll all die slowly, etc., etc.

So I'm going to go ahead and throw this slightly ridiculous question out to the masses to see if anyone's found a creative way to solve this problem before...

How can I use '/profiles' (and '/profiles/*', etc.) as URL aliases, while maintaining a fully functional, update-able Drupal instance?

Importantly, we're using the Global Redirect module, with the 'De-slash' and 'Non-clean to clean' options enabled (and they need to stay that way).

Comment: Never done this, hence a comment and not an answer, but since there isn't anything normally browsable in /profiles, I think your best bet is to add a RewriteRule to change the requested URL to another basepath.  This should get you past the /profile problem.  You then likely need to then inbound alter to remap back to /profile.

Comment: This is probably a silly question but couldn't we just put this "RewriteRule ^profiles/(.*) /index.php?q=profiles/$1" at the top of the htaccess file to rewrite all requests to /profiles to index.php?q=profiles/% or would this cause problems with updates / security

Comment: @MPD Sounds promising, I've had a go but not been able to get anything working

Comment: How was your site installed? is it from default profile or using some sort of distribution that has its installation profile and modules within the profiles directory?

Comment: @James it works for me :) try to add an answer and win +500!

Comment: @James Wont it cause an infinite loop ? as the non clean url will be rewritten to clean url again. i didnt try it out, just wondering. BTW question sounds like having the cake and eating it too.

Comment: @MarekSotak Profiles just contains the standard core stuff. Obviously if I can avoid just nuking that folder that would be great

Comment: @2-Stroker Yep that's exactly what happens. What do you mean by "having the cake and eating it too"? This sounds like a pretty reasonable request am I missing something? (I'm familiar with the expression, just not sure how it applies here?)

Comment: @kalabro James works in my office so he probably won't put an answer in for fairness sake :)

Comment: @kalabro the path is /profiles (with an 's' at the end) There's no 'profile' folder so if we were using that path there'd be no problem :)

Comment: @Clive that was a typo. I still confirm that method [from @James](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52882/using-profiles-in-a-url-alias#comment55746_52882) works if add it before [line 100](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/c5d6e6334fb7a71ecf1dbc7e06a7de8ad9547b27:/.htaccess#l100) for `profiles/`, `profiles`, `profiles/1` and any `?q=`.

Comment: @kalabro Is that with the Global Redirect module installed and the options in the question enabled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) .htaccess (before line 100):

```
RewriteRule ^profiles($|/(.*)) /index.php [L]
```

2) VirtualHost (for de-slash setting):

```
<Location /profiles>
     DirectorySlash Off
</Location>
```

Second part is needed only if you use Global Redirect "de-slash".

Comment: Awesome, the `DirectorySlash Off` directive seems to have done the trick. Thank you :)

Comment: Brilliant.  Well deserving of the bounty.