# How can I have a node with the URL /themes

Tags: uri

I've created a node and have given it the URL /themes. In full: http://site-name.com/themes.

Permissions on the Drupal system folder 'themes' mean that the URL /themes gives: 403 forbidden.

Is there anyway to have a node with /themes? I'd prefer if possible to keep my current file structure as I think it would be difficult to change with my current host (Pantheon).

Comment: Though I don't know if it is possible to use a path which is actually a core folder, I want to point out that you cannot change the file structure of Drupal, doesn't matter what hosting you have.

Comment: Yes, [it's possible](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52882/using-profiles-in-a-url-alias) in theory, but you'll need to get Pantheon to change their Nginx config to actually do it. That's not very likely in my experience, as they use a shared version for a lot of stuff. I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think even enterprise customers can get the web server conf changed (we tried once before). Either way, you really need to direct your query to them to find out if they can facilitate

Comment: Have you tried the Pathauto module to generate an alias?

http://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

Answer (score -3):

In your .htaccess file, the URL re-write has the a code to point the path to the respective folder, if present.. you can change that!

Comment: Danger danger!! Please don't mess with that

Comment: Yes, it's not advisable; but its the only solution to do that.

Comment: No, it's not a solution. You're assuming the OP's web server is Apache, which it isn't.