# Cannot use the alias "/libraries"

Tags: 8, path-aliases, uri

I am trying to make a node have the alias "/libraries" but I get a Page Not Found error which looks to be returned before Drupal has fully bootstrapped (I don't get the usual Drupal 404).

I checked a few other sites and they seem to have the same issue. Is there some reason why I cannot use this alias in Drupal? Would it have anything to do with a "libraries" folder in the root of the project?

Edit: It *does* appear to be because I have a "libraries" directory in the docroot which contain various JS libraries for CKEditor and other modules that need them.

So what is the fix here? I assume if I change the directory to anything else, those plugin paths will break. I could add Libraries API maybe, but I don't know the status of that module, but it still means any module that has a `libraries.yml` file that looks for `/libraries..../file.js` still won't work.

In this actual case, `/libraries` is a View (or could wind up being a node with a View block on it) that lists all libraries in the system, and thats what I want the URL to be.

Comment: this is happening before Drupal is bootstrapped in .htaccess, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` excludes existing directories getting to index.php

Comment: Makes sense. So, am I stuck here?

Comment: @Kevin This worked for me some years back: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52882/using-profiles-in-a-url-alias

Comment: I tried to implement a rule that matched `^libraries/$` which resulted in an endless redirect loop - how did you get around that with profiles? Note that I only want to allow the alias `/libraries` for a node that lists all library locations in the city - other nodes have a Pathauto pattern of `/libraries/[node:title]` and seem fine as-is.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking in the future, this will solve it.

Add this to your htaccess file:

```
# Allow the alias "/libraries" to work without breaking actual assets in the libraries directory.
RewriteRule ^libraries$ /index.php [L]
```

Just before this block:

```
  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I also had to add an `.htaccess` file to the libraries directory. Inside of that, I had to do:

```
DirectoryIndex ../index.php
DirectorySlash off
```

Now I can create an alias for `/libraries` and not introduce and endless redirect loop, and physical assets (CKEditor plugins) can still be loaded correctly from this directory.